# How to update the Opportunity Ownerid with the current Userid in "Before Delete" Trigger

Tags: apex, before-trigger

inside of a "Before Delete Trigger" I'm attempting to over-ride the record's owner ID with the User ID of the person performing the delete.  if I simply assign it in the trigger like this:

```
thisOpp.Ownerid = userId;
```

When I run it the delete fails with a "Record is Read-Only" error. Presumably because it's in an edit state.

One suggestion I was given in the Trailhead community was to try an in-line update:

```
trigger Opportunity_Delete_Trigger on Opportunity (before delete, after delete) {
    
    Id userId = userinfo.getUserId();
    
    if(trigger.isbefore)
     {
        for (Opportunity thisOpp: trigger.old) {
            thisOpp.update Ownerid = userId;
        }
     }
    
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be valid syntax as I get a compile error: (Invalid Type: thisOpp.update)

So how can I commit the change to the Ownerid field prior to the actual delete occurring?

Thanks,

Chris Campbell

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not in a delete trigger.

`delete` triggers only have access to `trigger.old` and `trigger.oldMap`, and both of those are read-only. The only real use that I know of for a "before delete" trigger is to catch and prevent deletion by using SObject's `.addError()` method.

It's not clear why you care about changing the owner (the record is going to be deleted, so why does that matter?). If you have some rule or process in place that dictates that only user X can delete records, changing the owner to allow other people to delete records is just a messy way to say "anybody can delete records".

Assuming that there is a reason behind this, you'd be better served by creating a custom action to first *update* your record (to set some field, let's say `Do_Delete__c`). You can then pick that up in a before update trigger, where you could edit the owner, and then slate the record for deletion in the after update context.

Comment: Hi Derek.  Thanks for your reply.  I believe the issue was that a given user needed to be able to delete an opportunity that was owned by someone else.  They could delete their own opportunities.  Just not opportunities owned by others.  The goal was to be able to allow this without having to implement custom permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The record is read-only

> `trigger.old` is always read-only.

but it is possible to update in `before delete`, if necessary

> `before delete`
>
> **Can update original object using an update DML operation**
>
> Allowed. The updates are saved before the object is deleted, so if the object is undeleted, the updates become visible.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm

```java
trigger Opportunity_Delete_Trigger on Opportunity(before delete) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
        for (Opportunity thisOpp : Trigger.old) {
            opportunitiesToUpdate.add(
                new Opportunity(Id = thisOpp.Id, OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId())
            );
        }
        update opportunitiesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will give this a shot.